# Visual Studio 2012 SQL Publish script generates Error for Column with Default value

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, constraints, default-value

I have an existing Table in my DB.  I added a Column to it with a default value.  something like this:

[MyNewColumn]   FLOAT   NOT NULL    DEFAULT(1)

and I'm getting an error when I try to publish to my DB via Visual studio.  the error is:
Column already has a DEFAULT bound to it

However I don't have any other constraints and the column didn't exist before.  The table existed with other columns.

If I generate the script I see that first the column is added like this:
GO
ALTER TABLE [MyTable]
    ADD 
        [MyNewColumn]  FLOAT (53) DEFAULT (1) NOT NULL;

and later in the script the following line (where the error occurs!) is written:
GO
ALTER TABLE [MyTable]
    ADD DEFAULT (1) FOR [MyNewColumn];

why is this happening and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug in Visual Studio but you should be able to work around it by setting these switches prior to publishing:

1. IgnoreColumnOrder = True
2. CheckNewConstraints = False

[Source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0d95ab4b-9d49-4f7b-8dbf-c43cf8e9d249/column-already-has-a-default-bound-to-it-when-updating-an-existing-database-using-vsdbcmd?forum=vstsdb)